# How to set gradient color to UIImageView border

Tags: ios, iphone, uiimageview, gradient

How to apply gradient color to UIImageView border color. What i tried is

```
let gradient: CAGradientLayer = CAGradientLayer()

    let color0 = UIColor(red:0.0/255, green:0.0/255, blue:0.0/255, alpha:0.0).CGColor
    let color1 = UIColor(red:0.0/255, green:0.0/255, blue: 0.0/255, alpha:0.71).CGColor

    gradient.colors = [color0, color1]
    gradient.locations = [0.0 , 1.0]
    gradient.frame =  CGRect(x: 0.0, y: 80.0, width: self.imgProfile.frame.size.width, height: self.imgProfile.frame.size.height-35)

    self.imgProfile.layer.insertSublayer(gradient, atIndex: 0)
```

This is what required

[image]

Please guide, thanks

Update:

Tried this way

```
let gradient = CAGradientLayer()
    gradient.frame =  CGRect(origin: CGPointZero, size: self.imgPeopleProfile.frame.size)
    gradient.colors = [UIColor.blueColor().CGColor, UIColor.greenColor().CGColor]

    let shape = CAShapeLayer()
    shape.lineWidth = 2
    shape.path = UIBezierPath(rect: self.imgPeopleProfile.bounds).CGPath
    shape.strokeColor = UIColor.blackColor().CGColor
    shape.fillColor = UIColor.clearColor().CGColor
    gradient.mask = shape

    imgPeopleProfile.layer.cornerRadius = imgPeopleProfile.frame.size.width / 2
    imgPeopleProfile.clipsToBounds = true
    self.imgPeopleProfile.layer.addSublayer(gradient)
```

It gives [image]

[image]

Comment: Your approach looks very good, can you tell us what result you ting?g

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Please take Imageview Size Equal width and height ex. Width=100 and Height = 100 So it will show proper Circle. If you want to change the Size then please amke also change in the below Line .

```
shape.path = UIBezierPath(arcCenter: CGPoint(x: 50, y: 50), radius: CGFloat(50), startAngle: CGFloat(0), endAngle:CGFloat(M_PI * 2), clockwise: true).CGPath
```

With the radius of the Circle in above example its 50.

```
 let gradient = CAGradientLayer()
            gradient.frame =  CGRect(origin: CGPointZero, size: self.imageView.frame.size)
            gradient.colors = [UIColor(red:87.0/255, green:206.0/255, blue: 172.0/255, alpha:0.71).CGColor,UIColor(red:44.0/255, green:192.0/255, blue:208.0/255, alpha:1.0).CGColor]

            imageView.layer.cornerRadius = imageView.frame.size.width / 2
            imageView.clipsToBounds = true

            let shape = CAShapeLayer()
            shape.lineWidth = 5
            shape.path = UIBezierPath(arcCenter: CGPoint(x: 50, y: 50), radius: CGFloat(50), startAngle: CGFloat(0), endAngle:CGFloat(M_PI * 2), clockwise: true).CGPath
            shape.strokeColor = UIColor.blackColor().CGColor
            shape.fillColor = UIColor.clearColor().CGColor
            gradient.mask = shape

            self.imageView.layer.addSublayer(gradient)
```

[image]

Comment: Already implemented this, it doesn't give you rounded corners and if you make corners round gradient color portion cuts off.

Comment: not accurate not generating as you show above. Please check update

Comment: Can you tell me your imageview frame please

Comment: please take your imageview as Size width=100 and height = 100 then it will appear correct way.

Comment: Oks..Make that Imageview Size equal width and height and you will get proper response.